# Left Bar Button Item - show name of previous View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, backbarbuttonitem

If you have a Navigation Controller with no Bar Button Items, a navigation **back button** will be shown with the **name of the last View Controller**.

I want to keep that name, as in I don't want to have to hardcode it. I do know how to add it in but I don't want to have to do that because that leaves more room for bugs.

Is there a way that I can have a left Bar Button Item and for the default one to not go away?

Comment: You want to have multiple left bar button item including default back button?

Comment: Yes. that is correct

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this in viewController where you want to have default back button and custom bar button item. You can customise the bar button item.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let newBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "new", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(anotherMethod))
    self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBtn//self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [newBtn,anotherBtn]
}
```