# Custom Back Indicator Image for Navigation Bar Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to set a custom image for the back bar button.  I can remove the text, however, the default chevron arrow is still there.  As illustrated below;

I'm on x-code 11.3

[image]

My code is;

```
let chevronImage = UIImage(systemName: "arrow.left")!.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -8, bottom: 0, right: 0))
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = chevronImage
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = chevronImage
```

Comment: Instead of `backBarButtonItem `,  try to change [leftbarbuttonitem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624936-leftbarbuttonitem)

Comment: That brings me back to the default backBarButton i.e. icon and title

Comment: It will override your back button with the custom button. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254254/left-bar-button-item

Comment: this does work, however, loses the default behaviour of the back barButtonItem. Is this correct?

Comment: Working example https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/02f14c9e358566d1c755d82de3f90c2924115c7d/bk2ch12p604NavigationBarAppearance/NavigationBarAppearance/TableViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "arrow.left"),
                                                   style: .plain,
                                                   target: nil,
                                                   action: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try create your own custom navigation bar class and use that in viewDidLoad() function

```
let backButtonBackgroundImage = UIImage(named: "ic_navbar_back")!
let barAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf[CustomNavBar.self])
barAppearance.backIndicatorImage = backButtonBackgroundImage
barAppearance.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backButtonBackgroundImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = images`
        `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = images`
`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.clear`